# Windows Phone ProgressBar style behind the code

Tags: styles, progress-bar, windows-phone

I need help to change my progressBar's style at runtime (Windows Phone).

Any example?
Is that possbile?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Matt! I did it! Gonna answer my question right now!

Answer (score 0):

Style on XAML:

```
   <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="PhoneProgressBarSliderThumb" TargetType="Thumb">
        <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Height="24" IsHitTestVisible="False" Width="24"/>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <Style x:Key="PhoneProgressBarSliderStyle" TargetType="Slider">
        <Setter Property="Maximum" Value="3000"/>
        <Setter Property="Minimum" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Value" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Slider">
                    <Grid IsHitTestVisible="False">
                        <Grid x:Name="HorizontalTemplate">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <RepeatButton x:Name="HorizontalTrackLargeChangeDecreaseRepeatButton" Grid.Column="0" Height="0" Template="{x:Null}"/>
                            <Thumb x:Name="HorizontalThumb" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Height="24" IsTabStop="False" Template="{StaticResource PhoneProgressBarSliderThumb}"/>
                            <RepeatButton x:Name="HorizontalTrackLargeChangeIncreaseRepeatButton" Grid.Column="2" Height="0" Template="{x:Null}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ProgressBarStyle1" TargetType="ProgressBar">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
        <!--<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>-->
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="YellowGreen"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
        <Setter Property="Maximum" Value="100"/>
        <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{StaticResource PhoneHorizontalMargin}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ProgressBar">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Determinate"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate">
                                    <Storyboard Duration="00:00:04.4" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="IndeterminateRoot">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="DeterminateRoot">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Value" Storyboard.TargetName="Slider1">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5" Value="1000">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                    <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Exponent="1"/>
                                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.0" Value="2000"/>
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.5" Value="3000">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                    <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseIn" Exponent="1"/>
                                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00.2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Value" Storyboard.TargetName="Slider2">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5" Value="1000">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                    <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Exponent="1"/>
                                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.0" Value="2000"/>
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.5" Value="3000">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                    <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseIn" Exponent="1"/>
                                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00.4" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Value" Storyboard.TargetName="Slider3">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5" Value="1000">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                    <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Exponent="1"/>
                                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.0" Value="2000"/>
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.5" Value="3000">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                    <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseIn" Exponent="1"/>
                                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00.6" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Value" Storyboard.TargetName="Slider4">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5" Value="1000">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                    <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Exponent="1"/>
                                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.0" Value="2000"/>
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.5" Value="3000">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                    <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseIn" Exponent="1"/>
                                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00.8" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Value" Storyboard.TargetName="Slider5">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5" Value="1000">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                    <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Exponent="1"/>
                                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.0" Value="2000"/>
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.5" Value="3000">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                                    <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseIn" Exponent="1"/>
                                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Slider1">
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.5" Value="0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00.2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Slider2">
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.5" Value="0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00.4" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Slider3">
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.5" Value="0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00.6" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Slider4">
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.5" Value="0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00.8" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Slider5">
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02.5" Value="0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid x:Name="DeterminateRoot" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Visibility="Visible">
                            <Rectangle x:Name="ProgressBarTrack" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="24" Opacity="0.1"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="ProgressBarIndicator" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <Border x:Name="IndeterminateRoot" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Visibility="Collapsed">
                            <Grid>
                                <Slider x:Name="Slider1" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneProgressBarSliderStyle}"/>
                                <Slider x:Name="Slider2" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneProgressBarSliderStyle}"/>
                                <Slider x:Name="Slider3" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneProgressBarSliderStyle}"/>
                                <Slider x:Name="Slider4" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneProgressBarSliderStyle}"/>
                                <Slider x:Name="Slider5" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneProgressBarSliderStyle}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>       
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

My .cs:

```
    progBar.Style = (Style)this.Resources["ProgressBarStyle1"];
```

> > > > > STYLE WAS FOUND ON INTERNET <<<<<